# Error when starting example code in JPVM

Tags: java, pvm

I am trying to run the example code provided with the `JPVM`,the java version of `PVM`. 
I am able to start the JPVM daemon without any errors but when I try to run the example provided I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jpvm/jpvmException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jpvm.jpvmException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: hello. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the examples from the examples directory, I copied the `.class` files into the `JPVM` root directory and ran them from there and it worked.
apparently the `jPVM` root directory is the working directory and examples need to be ran from there.